# ReflectionException in Container.php Class image does not exist for intervention

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5.1, intervention

I tried to save an image which comes form POST request using laravel. but it gives me the following error.

> > ReflectionException in Container.php line 741: Class image does not exist

I did the following things :
enabling the fileinfo extension in php.ini file
and `composer dumpautoload`
but nothing is work I followed the guide line [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel)
I am using laravel 5.1

my code is as bellow

```
public function saveImage(){

    Image::make(Input::file('files')->getRealPath())
        ->resize(870, null, true, false)
        ->save('foo.jpg');

}
```

Comment: Did you update your `config/app.php` for the `$providers` and `$aliases` ?

Comment: yes I put the aliases

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you include the class, in the top of the document?

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

Comment: Oh, it's the problem, intellij automatically use the use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
when I change it to use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;, then work fine
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that by adding the following to the config/app.php

```
 'providers' => [
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
    ],
    
    'aliases' => [
        'Image'     => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
    ],
```